After GDAL upgrade - can`t start my App which initializes the GDAL Coordinate system - looks like can`t read memory pointer
Previously I used MapServer v7.6.4 + GDAL v3.5.1 and PROJ7 data.
I now upgraded to use latest MapServer v8.2.2 + GDAL v3.10.0 and PROJ9 data.
After upgrade the GDAL/ my  app fails to initialize GDAL Coordinate system.
I have code which initializes GDAL Like (enabled logs and other info for debuging but it did not helped):
public static void Initialise()
{
    if (!_initialised)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Dev\MapServer";
        if (!File.Exists(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL))
        {
            var dataDirectory = Path.Combine(path, "GDAL-DATA");
            var mapSerberBin = Path.Combine(path, "bin");
            AddPath(mapSerberBin);

            // GDAL customizations for GEO goes in this msconf.ini, later you can override the value using Environment variables
            var mapServerConfigFile = Path.Combine(mapSerberBin, "msconf.ini");
            CPL.SetConfigOption("GDAL_CONFIG_FILE", mapServerConfigFile);

            CPL.SetConfigOption("CPL_LOG", @"C:\Logs\Normal\gdal_cpl_log.txt");
            CPL.SetConfigOption("CPL_CURL_VERBOSE", "YES");
            CPL.SetConfigOption("CPL_DEBUG", "ON");
            CPL.SetConfigOption("CPL_TIMESTAMP", "ON");
            
            CPL.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", dataDirectory);
            CPL.SetConfigOption("PROJ_DATA", Path.Combine(path, @"proj-data"));
            CPL.SetConfigOption("PROJ_LIB", Path.Combine(path, @"proj-data"));
            CPL.SetConfigOption("OSR_USE_ETMERC", "YES"); //"YES" ensures that GDAL uses the ETMERC algorithm instead of the older, less accurate implementation.
            CPL.SetConfigOption("OGR_CT_FORCE_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER", "YES"); // "YES" ensures that GDAL uses the traditional (longitude, latitude)
        }

        PROJ.proj_context_set_search_paths(IntPtr.Zero, 1, new[] { Path.Combine(path, @"proj-data") });

        GDALAllRegister();
        OGRRegisterAll();
        _initialised = true;

    }
}

I get error:
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'GdalProvider.GdalCoordinateSystem' threw an exception.
  Source=MyProject
  StackTrace:
   at GdalProvider.GdalCoordinateSystem..ctor(Int32 epsg) in …\GdalProvider\GdalCoordinateSystem.cs:line 45
   at CoordinateSystem.Create(Int32 epsgCode  
  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    GdalGrids.OsrSpatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCs(string) in OSRSpatialReference.cs
    ..    GdalProvider.GdalCoordinateSystem.GdalCoordinateSystem() in GdalCoordinateSystem.cs

Inner Exception 1:
AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

When calling:
var err = GOSRImportFromEPSGA(_ogrSpatialReferenceH, epsg))
// It is crashing, not getting ether err result.

Original GDAL method ref:
[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern OgrError OSRImportFromEPSGA(IntPtr handle, int epsg);
In a log I get only this:

How I could get more information why I can`t read _ogrSpatialReferenceH?
As my app simple kinda hands does not do anything forever after showing that error in the Visual Studio.
P.S.:
I wrote small LinqPad x64 C# Program and it runs successfully :/.
void Main()
{
    var msDir = @"C:\Dev\MapServer";
    // Specify the paths to the GDAL and PROJ data directories
    string gdalDataPath = Path.Combine(msDir,"gdal-data");
    string projDataPath = Path.Combine(msDir, "proj-data");
    string gdalBinPath = Path.Combine(msDir,"bin"); // Path to the directory containing gdal.dll
    AddPath(gdalBinPath);

    // Set the GDAL and PROJ environment variables - WORKS
    SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", gdalDataPath);
    SetConfigOption("PROJ_LIB", projDataPath);
    SetConfigOption("PROJ_DATA", projDataPath); 
    SetConfigOption("OSR_USE_ETMERC", "YES");
    SetConfigOption("OGR_CT_FORCE_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER", "YES");
    // Register GDAL and OGR drivers
    GDALAllRegister();
    OGRRegisterAll();   
    IntPtr spatialReference = OSRNewSpatialReference(null); // WORKS
    int epsgCode = 32631; // Example EPSG code
    
    if (spatialReference == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to create spatial reference.");
        return;
    }

    int result = OSRImportFromEPSGA(spatialReference, epsgCode);
    if (result != 0)    
    {
        IntPtr errorMsgPtr = CPLGetLastErrorMsg();
        string errorMsg = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errorMsgPtr);
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to import EPSG code {epsgCode}: {errorMsg}");
        OSRDestroySpatialReference(spatialReference);
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Successfully initialized spatial reference for EPSG code {epsgCode}.");

    // Clean up
    OSRDestroySpatialReference(spatialReference);
}

internal static class GdalWrapper
{
    internal const string GdalDLL = "gdal.dll"; // in GDAL v3.6 "gdal305.dll"
}

// P/Invoke declarations for GDAL functions
[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void GDALAllRegister();

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void OGRRegisterAll();

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr OSRNewSpatialReference(string wkt);

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int OSRImportFromEPSGA(IntPtr handle, int epsg);

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void OSRDestroySpatialReference(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr CPLGetLastErrorMsg();

[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void CPLSetConfigOption([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string key, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string value);


private static void SetGdalConfigOptionUsingEnv(string key, string value)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(key, value);
}

private static void SetConfigOption(string key, string value)
{
    CPLSetConfigOption(key, value);
}

private static void AddPath(string directoryName)
{
    string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? string.Empty;
    if (!path.Contains(directoryName))
    {
        path = directoryName + ";" + path;
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
    }
}

